# Queued messages and message alert does not show anything in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I used to see the queued messages and the message alert showing the number of the messages over time in the overview section of the RabbitMQ management. But right now I am running into the problem of not being able to see the messages in the message queue overview when I publish a message. Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the luxury to do so then: disconnect consumer from that queue, publish and see if message gets to queue (assuming you using rabbit management console (port 15672)), you can withdraw it too and see the payload. If you don't see the message there (make sure your message expiry date is long enough), then:

- do you have bindings between exchange <-> queue ?
- check your message routing key
- what exchange type you use and what is your routing key rule?

You should normally see the stats, therefore i'm more concern if you haven;t lost any of above configuration